# What is Barcode Reader support

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, point-of-sale

I am newbie into Point of sale software development, and by reviewing some pos software they mention that the program support barcode reader, but from what I know the barcode reader will take the responsibility of reading the barcode and generate string and it will just act as ordinary keyboard. So why it even need "support". Or am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of marketing.

Comment: @JJJ Haha, so that's it? just a marketing trick? I thought there is some magic behind that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many functions and configurable features that have to do with symbologies, delays and special characters.

If a POS advertises that they support barcode readers, I would look more in-depth for a list of brands and what scanner functions you can turn on and off through the software.

What they are implying is that their software has incorporated the SDK for the brands of scanners they support and allows configuration of options through screens in the system and not just by scanning the barcodes in the scanner's manual.

If they advertise that they support barcode readers and do not interact with the scanner except as a simulated keyboard, then I would agree that this is misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Entering barcode data over an emulated keyboard is cheap, and that is not really barcode support.  Any application that can take keyboard input can take such input.

In our POS solution, we read barcode data over a bidirectional serial port (a USB CDC COM device, aka USB-to-serial adapter or virtual COM port in the Windows world) and when the application starts, it will first program the scanner by sending commands to it.  That way we always start with a perfectly configured barcode scanner.  Reading barcode scanner data over a separate channel has the advantage that we can distinguish between keyboard input and scanner input.

Comment: aha thank you this is clearer now, but I'm curious to know this apply for any type of barcode scanner or only supported types (brands...)?

Comment: This works with almost any modern barcode scanner.  Most of them, if not all, support USB HID and USB CDC COM mode.